# My AJAX script is working fine in a 32 bit O/S and is giving error in a 64 bit OS

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax

We are working on password recovery with a security question and it is giving error access denied when running on a 64-bit machine.
But with a 32 bit machine it is working fine.
We used AJAX script for coding.Can you explain why is this error.

Comment: You didn't provide enough information.  Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot to go on in your post, but I've had issues deploying to a 64 bit machine in the past due to an IIS configuration problem.  To resolve my problem, I had to go into the IIS Management Console and "Allow" "ASP.NET 2.0.xx" in the "Web Service Extensions" Section.